# Java applet in firefox linux makes Java application launcher crash/exit

Tags: java, applet, cross-browser, jvm-crash

I have a Java applet that downloads data from where it's hosted, using HTTP. The applet has default permissions for an applet, that is, not many. Randomly during download, maybe 90% chance of reproductibility, at a specific part of the log, the `java` executable hosted by Firefox will exit abruptly, and the Java Console will be closed.

I thought it was my first JVM crash after just a few weeks of Java, but could not find the Fatal Error Log. Until I found out that when Chromium is used to open the applet, it works 100% (many tries in various conditions, alterning with Firefox)

Both browsers execute use the same commandlines for the `java` executable

```
Firefox:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java -D__jvm_launched=20972388862 -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/plugin.jar -Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/classes -Dsun.awt.warmup=true sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain write_pipe_name=/tmp/.com.sun.deploy.net.socket.5712.287531591049678510.AF_UNIX
Chromium: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/bin/java -D__jvm_launched=20858056974 -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/plugin.jar -Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/classes -Dsun.awt.warmup=true sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain write_pipe_name=/tmp/.com.sun.deploy.net.socket.5428.6724684151611746860.AF_UNIX
```

Then I booted a Windows 2000 partition and also noticed that the applet was working 100% with the same version of Firefox and JRE. Could not try Chrome, not available on this platform.

Now **I'm not necessarily asking for a solution** as my 'client' will use Windows 2000 to run the applet. I was posting this to know if someone experimented with java crashes could find an explanation to this. Is it the communication between Firefox Linux and `java` that could make `java` exit? If you had to make this work, how would you proceed? Try to produce an SSCCE for Mozilla?

Versions:

```
Firefox 9.0.1 (both on Linux and Windows 2000)
Chromium 9.0.597.45 (70550) Built on Debian 6.0, running on Debian 6.0.2
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

**EDIT**: I found more information. When listening to Firefox's stderr, running the applet and then exiting Firefox after `java` exits, I get this. Not so useful though, it just tends to show that Firefox didn't even know that `java` exited.

```
Exception in thread "main" netscape.javascript.JSException: Plugin instance for applet ID 1 was already released
at sun.plugin2.main.server.LiveConnectSupport.getInfo(LiveConnectSupport.java:405)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.LiveConnectSupport.shutdown(LiveConnectSupport.java:41)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMInstance.unregisterApplet(JVMInstance.java:1300)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMInstance.recycleAppletID(JVMInstance.java:385)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.JVMManager.recycleAppletID(JVMManager.java:316)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.MozillaPlugin.stopApplet(MozillaPlugin.java:325)
at sun.plugin2.main.server.MozillaPlugin.destroy(MozillaPlugin.java:225)
```

Comment: I now realize that this is more an informative post for people who would encounter the same issue so I wouldn't mind if it was closed by moderators. I guess there is nothing much to do except rely on Oracle or Mozilla's support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try to produce an SSCCE for Mozilla?

Yes.  (I recommend that.)

You will need it for a bug report to either Oracle or Mozilla.  Unless reported, problems do not get fixed.